# i created a project that can upload and download file, files that has been uploaded will be store in my hard disk.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My question is ,if i deploy  my project in  the web , will all the files that will be uploaded still will be store in my hard disk? i'm new in mvc ,i don't know much it yet.sorry very new in mvc

Answer (score 0):

Of course will not be on your hard disk cuz you set relative patch to upload/download file ("if i deploy my project in the web" - I guess it means deploy to external server, so i if you set static then propably program cause a error). Everything will be stored on device where program is running

Comment: so why do file system exist if it cant be stored in the disk sir?.. what should i do about it?

Comment: Everything will be stored on device where program is running

Comment: what do you mean with external server sir? sorry kinda new here sir. what i trying to ask like if my project is already hosted in a hosting site stil files cant be stored to my disk sir?

Comment: If you are histing your app on "local" PC then files will be saved locally. By "external server" i mean not your "local" PC but server

Comment: okay sir i got it. but hot to store the files that are uploaded if i deploy my project in the internet?